# Why did Medora kill her son?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, hold-the-dark

In the film Hold the Dark (2018), Medora seems to have killed her son Bailey.

In one scene as Medora is bathing, she is going on about a demon. But no demon is revealed by the time the movie ends.

So, Why did Medora kill her son Bailey?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The movie doesn't answer it. [Refinery 29 offers up this](https://www.refinery29.com/en-us/2018/09/212621/hold-the-dark-movie-ending-explained):

> Fine, fine, Russell is blessed by the wolf god. But that doesn't explain why Medora and Vernon did any of it. Why did they do it?
>
> Ah, that's the question. It's one that never quite gets answered, either. After surviving the shoot-out, Russell and Donald talk about the motivation behind the Sloanes' rampage. Russell is convinced these gaping questions had answers — but he and Donald may never truly understand them. "They do [have answers]. Whether or not they fit in our experience is another matter," he says. Russell and Donald aren't wild like the Sloanes. **Russell's theory? Medora wanted to spare the boy from a lifetime of darkness. The darkness that he'll inherit from his "other" parents and the darkness of their region, where the sun goes down at 3:30 p.m.**

This article tries to explain the whole movie, so perhaps it would be best to read all of it.